# Source code repository portal

Tags: svn

I am looking for a "portal" for wrapping our large Subversion repositories similar to GitHub.  Does anyone know of any options?  Features we are looking for are; home page for projects that include wiki bug tracking etc.  This would be for an internal deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I HIGHLY suggest [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).  It's powerful and full featured, yet somehow I find it very intuitive...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest http://www.assembla.com/ It is free for public projects. Also it supports private solution with price.